# How should I redirect stderr on commands that with arguement?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script I want to do:
`./xxx.sh -a 1 -b 2 -c 3  2>/dev/null`

However, the `2` is treated as argument

Similerly with the following command
`echo test 2>aaa.txt`

my intention is to direct strerr to aaa.txt, however, I got:

```
cat aaa.txt
test 2
```

as you can see `2` is also treated as an argument. How should I redirect stderr on commands that with argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are  using **csh** or **tcsh**
because 2> redirect does not work with csh or tcsh.

Use the `chsh` command to change your shell to /bin/sh or /usr/local/bin/bash in order to use the 2> style redirect. Note: Do not change root's shell to /usr/local/bin/bash

csh and tcsh cannot redirect standard out and error separately, but >& will redirect the combined output to a file.

and then you can try to use the same command or with "()"
like `( your command ) 2> /dev/null`

or you can also do it with 2 shells.

> Example: `csh -c 'SOME_COMMAND 1>/dev/null' |& tee file.txt`

Comment: Very nice catch.

Comment: Please not that if you are having this in scripts, you should investigate the shebang (first line that looks like `#!/usr/bin/env csh` or alike. If it states csh or tcsh, then the language of the script is csh and hence, should use csh syntax. As explained in this answer, csh has a different redirection syntax